# Python Class Input Improvement

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

In this code, I just try to get data from user about animal nutrition, respiratory, excretory and reproductive. Then, I put these animal data class by user animal type input. After that i create a file to save those data. It is just a exercise to improve myself.
My question is that even i put nutrition or etc data function in animal main class. I had to code another
function for nutrition or etc. for input specification. Is there any other simple way to do that without righting extra input function. For example, At the beginning of the code i had tried to put those input function into animal main class or subclasses of it. I couln't manage that.

Also, I would like to hear your improvement advise for my code.

Thank You for Your Time.

```
    # all class


class animal:

    def __init__(self, nutrition = "gg", respiratory = "gg", excretory = "gg", reproductive = "gg"):
        self.nutrition = nutrition
        self.respiratory = respiratory
        self.excretory = excretory
        self.reproductive = reproductive


class land(animal):

    def __init__(self, nutrition, respiratory, excretory, reproductive, climate, animal_type):
        super().__init__(nutrition, respiratory, excretory, reproductive)
        self.climate = climate
        self.animal_type = animal_type

    def land_show_info(self):
        return "Animal Type: {}\nNutrition: {}\nRespiratory: {}\nExcretory: {}\nReproductive: {}\nClimate: {}\n".format(
            self.animal_type, self.nutrition, self.respiratory, self.excretory, self.reproductive, self.climate)


class sea(animal):

    def __init__(self, nutrition, respiratory, excretory, reproductive, climate, animal_type):
        super().__init__(nutrition, respiratory, excretory, reproductive)
        self.climate = climate
        self.animal_type = animal_type

    def land_show_info(self):
        return "Animal Type: {}\nNutrition: {}\nRespiratory: {}\nExcretory: {}\nReproductive: {}\nClimate: {}\n".format(
            self.animal_type, self.nutrition, self.respiratory, self.excretory, self.reproductive, self.climate)


class air(animal):

    def __init__(self, nutrition, respiratory, excretory, reproductive, climate, animal_type):
        super().__init__(nutrition, respiratory, excretory, reproductive)
        self.climate = climate
        self.animal_type = animal_type

    def land_show_info(self):
        return "Animal Type: {}\nNutrition: {}\nRespiratory: {}\nExcretory: {}\nReproductive: {}\nClimate: {}\n".format(
            self.animal_type, self.nutrition, self.respiratory, self.excretory, self.reproductive, self.climate)


# all class input function
def nutrition():
    while True:
        nutrition = input("""
        Please Enter Nutrition Type
        1. Carnivorous    --> 'c'
        2. Herbivorous    --> 'h'
        3. Omnivorous     --> 'o'
        4. No Information --> 'n'\n""")
        if nutrition == 'c':
            nutrition = "Carnivorous"
            break
        elif nutrition == 'h':
            nutrition = "Herbivorous"
            break
        elif nutrition == 'o':
            nutrition = "Omnivorous"
            break
        elif nutrition == 'n':
            nutrition = "No Information"
            break
        else:
            print("""!WARNING!
            ...Improper Input Detected...""")
    return nutrition


def respiratory():
    while True:
        respiratory = input("""
        Please Enter Respiratory Type
        1. with Oxygen    --> '+o2'
        2. without Oxygen --> '-o2'
        3. No Information --> 'n'\n""")
        if respiratory == '+o2':
            respiratory = "with Oxygen"
            break
        elif respiratory == '-o2':
            respiratory = "without Oxygen"
            break
        elif respiratory == 'n':
            respiratory = "No Information"
            break
        else:
            print("""!WARNING!
            ...Improper Input Detected...""")
    return respiratory


def excretory():
    while True:
        excretory = input("""
        Please Enter Excretory Type
        1. Ammonia         --> 'a'
        2. Urea           --> 'u'
        3. Uric Acid      --> 'ua'
        4. No Information --> 'n'\n""")
        if excretory == 'a':
            excretory = "Ammonia"
            break
        elif excretory == 'u':
            excretory = "Urea"
            break
        elif excretory == 'ua':
            excretory = "Uric Acid"
            break
        elif excretory == 'n':
            excretory = "No Information"
            break
        else:
            print("""!WARNING!
            ...Improper Input Detected...""")
    return excretory


def reproductive():
    while True:
        reproductive = input("""
        Please Enter Reproductive Type
        1. Sexual         --> 's'
        2. Asexual        --> 'a'
        3. No Information --> 'n'\n""")
        if reproductive == 's':
            reproductive = "Sexual"
            break
        elif reproductive == 'a':
            reproductive = "Asexual"
            break
        elif reproductive == 'n':
            reproductive = "No Information"
            break
        else:
            print("""!WARNING!
            ...Improper Input Detected...""")
    return excretory


def climate():
    while True:
        climate = input("""
        Please Enter Climate Type
        1. Desert         --> 'd'
        2. Forest         --> 'f'
        3. Tundra         --> 't'
        4. Ice Field      --> 'i'
        5. No Information --> 'n'\n""")
        if climate == 'd':
            climate = "Desert"
            break
        elif climate == 'f':
            climate = "Forest"
            break
        elif climate == 't':
            climate = "Tundra"
            break
        elif climate == 'i':
            climate = "No Ice Field"
            break
        elif climate == 'n':
            climate = "No Information"
            break
        else:
            print("""!WARNING!
            ...Improper Input Detected...""")
    return climate


def animal_type():
    while True:
        animal_type = input("""
        Please Enter Animal Type
        1. Land --> 'l'
        2. Sea  --> 's'
        3. Air  --> 'a'\n""")
        if animal_type == 'l':
            animal_type = "Land"
            break
        elif animal_type == 's':
            animal_type = "Sea"
            break
        elif animal_type == 'a':
            animal_type = "Air"
            break
        else:
            print("""!WARNING!
            ...Improper Input Detected...""")
    return animal_type


# input from user
nutrition = nutrition()
respiratory = respiratory()
excretory = excretory()
reproductive = reproductive()
climate = climate()
animal_type = animal_type()

# animal classification
if animal_type == 'Land':
    animal1 = land(nutrition, respiratory, excretory, reproductive, climate, animal_type)
    print(animal1.land_show_info())
elif animal_type == 'Sea':
    animal1 = sea(nutrition, respiratory, excretory, reproductive, climate, animal_type)
    print(animal1.land_show_info())
else:
    animal1 = air(nutrition, respiratory, excretory, reproductive, climate, animal_type)
    print(animal1.land_show_info())

# Is there a better way to check file is there or not by program itself
while True:
    file_ = input("""Is there a file on C:/Users/Gökberk/Desktop/Animal List.txt directory\n(y/n)""")
    if file_ == "y":
        with open("C:/Users/Gökberk/Desktop/Animal List.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write("##############################\n")
            file.write(animal1.land_show_info())
            break
    elif file_ == "n":
        with open("C:/Users/Gökberk/Desktop/Animal List.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8" ) as file:
            file.write("...Welcome to Animal List File...\n")
            file.write("##############################\n")
            file.write(animal1.land_show_info())
        print("File has been created to C:/Users/Gökberk/Desktop/Animal List.txt")
        break
    else:
        print("""!WARNING!
            ...Improper Input Detected...""")

print("Program is Over")
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is that creating dictionaries for each specification as I share code below,
into a one info_dict class then creating parametric input function 
into animal main class(if its possible)

```
nutrition = {1: "Carnivorous",
             2: "Herbivorous",
             3: "Omnivorous",
             4: "No Information",
             input_text: """Please Enter Nutrition Type
                            1. Carnivorous
                            2. Herbivorous
                            3. Omnivorous 
                            4. No Information\n"""}

respiratory = {1: "with Oxygen",
               2: "without Oxygen",
               3: "No Information",
               input_text: """Please Enter Respiratory Type
                              1. with Oxygen
                              2. without Oxygen
                              3. No Information\n"""}
```